# Vuetify breakpoints not breaking?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am having an issue with Vuetify not breaking my flex boxes like expected when viewing on small screen. I expect the form to break into 3 parts each spanning 12 cols when viewing on a small screen. However what happens is it just retains it's size from the original. It does not stack verticly like expected. The template code is below;

EDIT: I can tell that vuetify is updating the the breakpoints, but the layout does not change. If I set a computed property to this.$vuetify.breakpoint.lgandup I can see that when changing the screen size the boolean changes to false when it should and back to true when it should. But the layout does not change.

EDIT: I've updated my question with some more information and tried to include all relevant files.

EDIT: I want to add that I have figured out a small work around, by adding 'wrap'.. `<v-layout row wrap>` however it seems that this would not be needed since I'm already telling vuetify to break that into a full 12 col span on small screens, so there shouldn't be anything to wrap. Still looking for more insight here.

```
main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

// Override default theme for Vuetify
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'mdi',
  theme: {
    "primary": "#673ab7",
    "secondary": "#757575",
    "accent": "#d500f9",
    "error": "#ff1744",
    "info": "#d500f9",
    "success": "#4caf50",
    "warning": "#ff9100"
  }
})

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')



app.vue
<template>

  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <nav-draw/>
      <nav-bar/>
      <v-content>
        <v-container fluid>
          <v-layout row>
            <v-flex x12 sm12 md12 lg1 xl1>
              Test
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex xs12 sm12 md12 lg9 xl9>
              {{ this.$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndDown }}
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex xs12 sm12 md12 lg2 xl2>
              {{ this.$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp }}
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>

      </v-content>
      <v-footer app>2019 .com</v-footer>
    </v-app>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import NavDraw from '@/components/NavDraw'
import NavBar from '@/components/NavBar'

export default {
  components: {NavDraw, NavBar }
}
</script>


public/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<%= webpackConfig.output.publicPath 

    %>favicon.ico">
    <title>FranchiseFaves</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but this app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
      <div id="app"></div>

    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What version is this?

Comment: Vuetify 1.4.3 and Vue 2.5.22

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the `<div id="app">` in you app.vue. because you already call it in 
`public/index.html`